# Async Requests in Spark Java

Tags: rest, asynchronous, spark-java

I use spark-java framework. I would like implement async requests in REST APIs Because it has long running processes may takes more than a minute. I would like to have below workflow

1. Client makes a request
2. Server receives a request process it in async fashion(in separate thread)
3. Server sends success SUCCESS response to the client immediately as soon as it received the request, But actual process is under process

Is it possible to make implementation such that client knows automatically when server has finished processing ? Client may check the status of the request in periodic fashion from another REST API. But Is it possible without doing that like any kind of listeners?

I have gone through Servlet's async requests, Though the server runs in async fashion the client has to wait till it completes.

Otherwise Is it possible to avoid ELB Timeout currently it has 1 min.